# Does LWC map positive numbered tabindex values to zero?

Tags: lightning-web-components

With this LWC markup:

```
<td key={day.key} class={day.classes} tabindex={day.dayNumber}>
    <span class="slds-day" data-day-number={day.dayNumber} onclick={handleClick}>
        {day.dayOfMonth}
    </span>
</td>
```

I get this in the DOM:

```
<td cvnp-datepicker_datepicker="" tabindex="0">
    <span cvnp-datepicker_datepicker="" data-day-number="7325" class="slds-day">
       22
    </span>
</td>
```

i.e. something seems to map the `tabindex` to zero.

From a quick Google I found e.g. [Don’t Use Tabindex Greater than 0](https://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html); is LWC mapping the positive numbered `tabindex` to zero? Or is this a browser thing?

(Just spent 10 minutes trying to figure out what was wrong with the markup but now thinking it is not that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the answer in red lettering in the Developer Console:

> aura_proddebug.js:4763 Error: [LWC error]: Invalid tabindex value
>   `7479` in template for [object:vm undefined (10)]. This attribute must
>   be set to 0 or -1.

so I had to add another property for the `tabindex`:

```
        get tabIndex() {
            // Positive tabindex is an error in LWC
            return this.dayNumber ? 0 : undefined;
        },
```

Comment: In addition, you might need to explicitly set the tabindex to `-1` instead of `undefined`. "If not specified, it takes the default value 0." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex